# Search in two tables and retrieve main table results: Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel and have come across an issue.

I have a main table for my listings that I wish to search and I have this working fine for any matching strings for columns in this table. The problem is with entering a search term from a joined second table. I have set up the relationships correctly in the models. When I do a print_r I can see that the relationships are working, in that I can see all the columns in both tables. I think it is something to do with the fact that both tables contain columns called 'name', so it is possibly getting confused.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction, as I have tried larval IRC channel and looked on Google, but to no avail :(

Many thanks... (please see my code at this link: http://laravel.io/bin/aKDW - I think line 16 is the main issue)

Answer (score 0):

Use `orWhereHas`:

```
Beach::where('beach.name', 'LIKE', "%{$q}%")
     ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$q}%")
     ->orWhereHas(['countryJoin' => function($q){ $q->where('countryJoin.name', 'LIKE', "%{$q}%"); }])
     ->with('countryJoin', 'imageJoin')
     ->get();
```